# UIActivityIndicatorView doesn't stop at the right time

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to share video from my app with `UIActivityViewController`.
So, the process looks like that:

1. User is tapping on Share button.
2. I have to prepare video for him with my function `saveToShare()`.
3. I'm starting animation for my UIActivityIndicatorView and launching `saveToShare()`.
4. I'm sending notification from `saveToShare` to my controller.
5. Observer in my controller is launching function `shareVideo()`.
6. `shareVideo()` looks like that:

   ```
   func videoIsReady() {
   self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
   self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true


   let videoName = "NewWatermarkedVideoNew2Share.mov"
   let exportPath = NSTemporaryDirectory().appending(videoName)
   let exportUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: exportPath)

   let urlData = NSData(contentsOf: exportUrl)

   if ((urlData) != nil){

       let videoLink = exportUrl

       let objectsToShare = [videoLink] 
       let activityVC = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: objectsToShare, applicationActivities: nil)
       activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view // so that iPads won't crash
       activityVC.setValue("#myhashtag", forKey: "subject")

       activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityType.airDrop, UIActivityType.addToReadingList, UIActivityType.assignToContact, UIActivityType.copyToPasteboard, UIActivityType.openInIBooks, UIActivityType.postToTencentWeibo, UIActivityType.postToVimeo, UIActivityType.postToWeibo, UIActivityType.print, UIActivityType.saveToCameraRoll, UIActivityType.postToFlickr, UIActivityType.postToTwitter, UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.reminders.RemindersEditorExtension"), UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobilenotes.SharingExtension"),UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.google.Drive.ShareExtension"), UIActivityType(rawValue: "com.apple.mobileslideshow.StreamShareService")]

       self.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: {

       })


   } else {
       print("url is empty...")
   }

   }
   ```

It works, but my `UIActivityIndicatorView` is not hidden before share dialog and actually is working for several seconds after that dialog is shown.

What is wrong here?

P.S. So, it works if I put `UIActivityIndicatorView` in `DispatchQueue.main.async` so my problem is solved but I don't know why this problem was arisen in the first place.

Comment: Show me the code where you are starting it?

Comment: Threading problem.

Comment: @User511 the code is very simple: self.activityIndicator.startAnimating()

Comment: @matt yeah, I just used DispatchQueue.main.async and it works like a charim, but I don't understand why do I have to do this in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to disappear immediately, you'll want to call the code on the main queue synchronously. To avoid a dead lock (in case `videoIsReady()` is called from the main queue) use this little extension I've developed:

```
extension DispatchQueue {

    class func safeUISync(execute workItem: DispatchWorkItem) {
        if Thread.isMainThread { workItem.perform() }
        else                   { DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: workItem) }
    }

    class func safeUISync<T>(execute work: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        if Thread.isMainThread { return try work() }
        else                   { return try DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: work) }
    }
}
```

Now you can call your code as follows:

```
func videoIsReady() {
    DispatchQueue.safeUISync {
        self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
        self.activityIndicator.isHidden = true
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be calling your `videoIsReady()` function from a background thread. All UI calls must be made from the main thread or the results are undefined. A common result is for the UI changes to take a LOOONG time to appear. (Another common result is a crash.)

Comment: thanks! will it be enough to use 'DispatchQueue.main.async' for UI changes, or I have to use 'DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async' for resource-consuming operations?